# Getting my paths/breadcrumb right with views

Tags: 7, path-aliases, uri, breadcrumbs

Is it possible to get SEO friendly URLs when using a view? I have a site I am building that has a homepage which leads to two main views ("Homme" and "Femme"). I need the URL and breadcrumb to read "Home >> Homme >> name-of-the-article." Then, on the article page, I need "Homme" to be a link. Pretty straight forward and what you would expect in a site, right? I did download and install the Pathauto module, but I can't seem to get it working. I have a custom content type called "Men's blog post" and I set the path to be: "homme/[node:title]";  something similar is for "Femme."

This is not working. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Does the node title in the url include spaces? IF so, know that the spaces in the name which do not work well in urls.  You should set the title to have dashes to be a machine readable title. To do so change the configuration settings in pathauto to use a '-' separator.

Comment: Ok not sure why it wasn't working before but it is now. Problem I am having now is the breadcrumbs aren't updating to follow the path. How does this work?

Comment: Also paths not working for the basic page? I have emptied the cache plenty of times and made I saved the edits. Why isn't this working... ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I have a breadcrumb problem as well, but I have not gotten around to investigating it yet.  The fact that the paths are now working for articles, but not for basic pages raises the same question.  Do you have spaces in the url?  What is the autopath for your basic page?.  What exactly is being displayed in the URL?

Comment: I don't think I have spaces in the url. I am getting this for the basic page http://fource:8082/?q=content/prada and the pattern is black-book/[current-page:title] It is using the default at the moment. The list just shows content/prada. I tried updating the content and flushing all caches. Nothing

Comment: I assume prada is the name of the page.  If your URL is asking for content/prada it will not find a page called black-book/prada.

Comment: You may want to consider turning on Clean URLs at Home » Administration » Configuration » Search and metadata

Comment: clean urls isn't working... Not sure why. Guess I have to read the handbook.

Comment: got a copy of the .htaccess file and it is all good now.